# Fire server click after confirmation from end user using jConfirm

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want the server click event on a button to be fired after the client click returns true. Client click event handler gets confirmation from end user. For confirmation from end user, I am using jConfirm. But, issue is server click event is getting triggered irrespective of the confirmation from end user. It's working as expected if I use javascript confirmation dialog box.

What I need to do for the server click event to trigger after confirmation from end user?

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="ADD" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" ValidationGroup="Add" CausesValidation="true" OnClientClick="return Validate()" />


 function Validate() {
         alert(Page_ClientValidate('Add'));
         if (Page_ClientValidate('Add')) {
             if ($('#<%=ddlTestField.ClientID%>').val() == '0') {
                //return confirm("Select Confirm to apply this approval flow rule to all SOW requisition types. Otherwise, hit Cancel and select a specific requisition type for the approval flow rule.");
                 var strMessage = 'Continue?';
                 $.alerts.okButton = 'OK';
                 $.alerts.cancelButton = 'CANCEL';
                 return jConfirm(strMessage, 'CONFIRM MESSAGE', function (r) {

                    return r;
                });
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution

```
function Validate() { 
     var HasConfirmed = false;
     if (Page_ClientValidate('Add')) {                
         if ($('#<%=ddlTestField.ClientID%>').val() == '0') {
             var strMessage = 'Continue?';
             $.alerts.okButton = 'OK';
             $.alerts.cancelButton = 'CANCEL';
             jConfirm(strMessage, 'CONFIRM MESSAGE', function (r) {
                    HasConfirmed = r;
                    if (r) {
                        <%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Button1, String.Empty) %>;
                    }
                    return HasConfirmed;
                });
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return HasConfirmed;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Because jConfirm Ok/Cancel click is a separate event. Button1 Click is not waiting for jConfirm dialog.

Now on Button1 click show jConfirm dialog and return true so page will postback.

Use a normal html button and show jConfirm on this button's click event and after confirm call asp:button click.

```
<input type="button" onclick="Validate();" value="ADD" />
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="ADD" style="display:none;" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" ValidationGroup="Add" CausesValidation="true"  />


function Validate() {
     alert(Page_ClientValidate('Add'));
     if (Page_ClientValidate('Add')) {
         if ($('#<%=ddlTestField.ClientID%>').val() == '0') {
            //return confirm("Select Confirm to apply this approval flow rule to all SOW requisition types. Otherwise, hit Cancel and select a specific requisition type for the approval flow rule.");
             var strMessage = 'Continue?';
             $.alerts.okButton = 'OK';
             $.alerts.cancelButton = 'CANCEL';
             return jConfirm(strMessage, 'CONFIRM MESSAGE', function (r) {

                $("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>").click();
            });
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, show jconfirm from server click event using RegisterClientScriptBlock? or something else?

Comment: I have already tried this. But, it's not working. The server click event is getting fired before confirmation from end user. Now, if  I click on OK,then as it did a postback, blanks out all the fields & again executes the server click event

Comment: I guess You are suggesting to add an extra button to show the jConfirm

Comment: Yes. a normal html button

Comment: Hmmm.. But I can't add an extra button, that will change UI

Comment: no. Button1 is hidden when add 'style="display:none;"'. UI will not change